# Make character count, count emoji's as 2

Tags: string, bytes

I have the following function:

```
function getCharacterCount(string str) constant
returns (uint length)
{
    uint i=0;
    bytes memory string_rep = bytes(str);

    while (i<string_rep.length)
    {
        if (string_rep[i]>>7==0)
            i+=1;
        else if (string_rep[i]>>5==0x6)
            i+=2;
        else if (string_rep[i]>>4==0xE)
            i+=3;
        else if (string_rep[i]>>3==0x1E)
            i+=4;
        else
            //For safety
            i+=1;

        length++;
    }
}
```

Right now it totally works for all utf-8 strings so `getCharacterCount(test1234)` returns 8 but `getCharacterCount(test1234)`returns 9 where I want it to return 10. I could not find any working solution for this issue.

Comment: It actually depends what you consider a 'char'. Technically the previous version was correct if you consider that  is one unicode codepoint (char). Other emoji (eg ) will use two unicode codepoint; the previous version would give 2 as length for the latter while the new one would give you 4.

Comment: @mirg, They appear to be calculating the number of 16-bit words in the UTF-16 encoding of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding length once per character, so whichever case represents emojis, you need to use `length++;` in that case as well as the final `length++;`

Edit:

Using

`else if (string_rep[i]>>3==0x1E) {
    i+=4;
    length++;
}`

worked for me.

Comment: This does work!